# combo box getting data from notepad

Tags: c#, combobox

I have combo box and i need to get data from notepad while form load. my code is

```
    private string[] items;

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (cmbItems.SelectedIndex == -1)
        {
            items= File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\atchyutkumar\Downloads\data.txt");
        }
```

Comment: You *need to get data from notepad* but read from file? What is your question?

Comment: @i4v: probably "notepad can edit this file,therefor it's a notepad file".

Answer (score 2):

If your intension is to read all lines from a text file and put them into a combobox

```
cmbItems.Items.AddRange(File.ReadAllLines(filename));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   StreamReader sr = new Streamreader(YourTxtFilePath);
   string str = null;
   while( (str = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
   {
     if (cmbItems.SelectedIndex == -1) // If the comboBox is empty
     {
       cmbItems.Items.Add(str);     // Add the strings in the .txt file
     }
   }
}
```

I'm not sure if this is what you want or my code might be wrong. So, feel free to correct me. ;)

Comment: Good, except this will stop working as soon as there are 1 or more `Items` in the `ComboBox`.

Comment: @Evanlewis I agree. Changed the code. ;)